# Classifying the stationary point of $f(x, y) = 2x^4-3x^2y+y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find and classify the stationary point on the surface $f(x, y) = 2x^4-3x^2y+y^2$

I found the only stationary point for this surface is at $(0,0)$ but the determinant of the Hessian matrix for this surface is zero and I don't know how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: There are at least three questions in the handy list of related questions at right that describe the same situation. Look through the answers to those for how to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characterizing the critical point of a two-variable function when the Hessian determinant is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497499/characterizing-the-critical-point-of-a-two-variable-function-when-the-hessian-de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $(0,0)$ is the only critical point of $f$. Since the Hessian at $(0,0)$ is singular we need algebraic tricks in order to characterize the behavior of $f$ at this point. In the case at hand the trick consists in writing $f$ in the form
$$f(x,y)=(2x^2-y)(x^2-y)\ .$$
This shows that $f(x,y)\equiv0$ along two parabolas touching at $(0,0)$. These parabolas partition the plane into four subsets in which $f(x,y)$ has eiter positive or negative sign. The point $(0,0)$ belongs to the boundary of each of these subsets. It follows that you can call $(0,0)$ a saddle point of $f$. In any case $(0,0)$ is neither a local minimum nor a local maximum of $f$.