# Critical points with Hessian determinant equals to zero

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Consider the function $$f(x, y) = x^4+y^4-y^2$$

After having compute the gradient, I found the following critical points

$$p_0 = (0, 0) \qquad \qquad p_{1, 2} = \left(0, \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Now I followed this question: [Characterizing the critical point of a two-variable function when the Hessian determinant is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497499/characterizing-the-critical-point-of-a-two-variable-function-when-the-hessian-de?noredirect=1) to understand how to work with $(0, 0)$ and I got it.

The other points though, I need confirmation.

The function is even, so the two points must be the same type.

Now, I thought of this: the hessian reads

$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 12 x^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 12y^2 - 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

I could study the determinant and find where it's positive, hence where the function is convex.

$$12x^2(12y^2-2) > 0$$

Which gives the solution $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}$ and $y < -\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}$

Now, since my critical points are beyond the solutions, I can say that the determinant of the Hessian is positive at $\left(1, \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$, (for every neighbourhood $\epsilon$ of zero of $x$) hence the two points are two minima.

I wanted to understand also the other way (assuming this is correct), that is the restrictions as done in the linked question. But here I got stuck, because my function would read:

$$f\left(\epsilon, +\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right) = \epsilon^4 - \frac{1}{4}$$

Which is always negative for every neighbourhood $\epsilon \to 0$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't $p_{1, 2}$ be $(0, \pm \sqrt{1/2})$?

Comment: Also, why is it a problem that $f(\epsilon, +\sqrt{1/2})$ is negative in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$? I thought your goal is to show that $f(\epsilon, + \sqrt{1/2}) \geq f(0, + \sqrt{1, 2})$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$?

Comment: @KennyWong My bad! Thank you! Going to correct.

Comment: @KennyWong Oh! I just realized! That inequality always holds, hence I have a minimum at $p_1$ and also t $p_2$. Didn't think about that, thank you again!

Comment: Really, you want to prove that $f(\epsilon_1, \sqrt{1/2} + \epsilon_2) \geq f(0, \sqrt{1/2}$ for small enough $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ - in other words, $f$ increases if you move a small distance away from $(0, \sqrt{1/2})$ _in any direction_.